# Creating new exception that receives parameters

Tags: c++, exception

Hi I'm trying to create new exception that receives parameters and sends string to base class.

**Code**

```
class EmptyFunctionException : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    EmptyFunctionException(std::string filename, std::string funcname){
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << filename << " " << funcname;
        std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }
};
```

**Error**

> Base class 'runtime_error' doesn't have default constructor.

I know i need to send it like that

```
EmptyFunctionException(std::string filename, std::string funcname)
  : std::runtime_error(...)
```

but How can I create the string before that?

Thanks.

Comment: Even better: `const std::string& filename` when defining arguments.

Comment: How about `runtime_error(filename + " " + funcname)`?

Comment: doesn't the compiler makes it that passing const reference is the same speed as passing by value?

Comment: @0x499602D2 ^ Which would fit well for the [second constructor definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error).

Comment: 0x499602D2, is that the only way?

Comment: @Koten What's bothering you with it? Do you actually need more sophisticated formatting?

Comment: @Koten Is it not sufficient?

Comment: What if I pass "A" + filename?

Answer (score 2):

The class declaration for std::runtime_error has no default constructor and thus requires you to call the base constructor in your inherited class's constructor. I know you said that in your question but it's an important fact to list here.

Don't use stringstream to construct a more complicated string. In this instance it's easy to just construct the string in the base type's constructor.

```
class EmptyFunctionException : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    EmptyFunctionException(std::string filename, std::string funcname) : 
      std::runtime_error(filename + " " + funcname) 
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: It would be even better if the arguments were taken by `const` reference.

Comment: I agree with you @5gon12eder. However, I was just answering the question not giving him a code review.

Comment: @5gon12eder, doesn't the compiler makes it that passing const reference is the same speed as passing by value?

Comment: @Koten Maybe, if it is smart. And if `filename` and `funcname` are short enough for short-string-optimization, it won't matter at all. However, passing by `const` reference will never be slower and maybe be faster in this case, so I'd just go for it.

Comment: @Koten The rule of thumb is to give as many hints to the compiler as possible. In this case passing by const reference is the way to go. Sorry that isn't reflected in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would go the way, not to set the `what()` message of the base exception in the constructor actually, but overwrite the `what()` method according to your needs:

```
class EmptyFunctionException : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    EmptyFunctionException(const std::string filename&, const std::string& funcname
    : std::runtime_error(""), filename_(filename), funcname_() {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << filename << " " << funcname;
        msg_ = ss.str();
    }

    const char* what() const noexcept {
        return msg_.c_str();
    }

private:
    std::string filename_;
    std::string funcname_;
    std::string msg_;
};
```

Since `what()` is declared as `virtual` in the very base, and it's the only method affected by the required base exception argument, it seems best to overwrite it.

---

Though, then I would think about, what's the whole purpose of a specific `EmptyFunctionException`? Should there be some special logic for handling it beyond a `runtime_error`, or is it just purposed to do the error message formatting?

In the latter case, that could simply be done, before throwing the exception.

Comment: I think the signature of what() needs to be `const char* what() const noexcept`

Answer (score 0):

If you really need sophisticated formatting and simple concatenation would not do, you can always have an intermediate class:

```
class EmptyFunctionException : public std::runtime_error {
    struct ErrorFormatter {
        ErrorFormatter(const std::string& filename, const std::string funcname)             
        { 
             std::stringstream ss;
             ss << filename << " " << funcname;
             errstr = ss.str();
        }  
        const std::string& str() const { return errstr; }
        private:
        std::string errstr;
    };
public:
    EmptyFunctionException(std::string filename, std::string funcname) : 
        std::runtime_error(ErrorFormatter(filename, funcname).str()) {}
};
```

Comment: Why not just a (`static` member) function?

Comment: @5gon12eder I've come to the conclusion, that probably the whole derived exception is pointless. `static` member function returning `std::string` would also work.